# mod_rewrite for Typical CMS-style Redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, vhosts

Is there a specific `RewriteRule` that would work for Magento and convert

```
http://<domainname>/index.php/<filename>
```

into

```
http://<domainname>/<filename>
```

According to `phpinfo()`, **`Loaded Modules`** lists `mod_rewrite` , so it appears to be enabled.

Here is the relevant section from `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it wasn't a missing mod_rewrite rule. I fixed it by inserting the `Directory` section below into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.magecom.local.conf` (The `Directory` section didn't exist at all in the previous version).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dev.magecom.local
ServerAlias www.dev.magecom.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/dev.magecom.local/public_html/

    <Directory /var/www/sites/dev.magecom.local/public_html/>
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```